# Return ResultSet with column names from postgresql Stored procedures

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, resultset

I have the following postgresql Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION readMessage(messageFor INT, qid INT = NULL, ctxt INT = NULL, messageFrom INT = NULL, byTimeStamp BOOLEAN = FALSE)
RETURNS SETOF message
AS $$
DECLARE
    sql varchar;
BEGIN
    sql := 'SELECT * FROM message WHERE (receiver_id IS NULL OR receiver_id = $1)';
    IF qid IS NOT NULL THEN
        sql := sql || ' AND queue_id = $2';
    END IF;
    IF ctxt IS NOT NULL THEN
        sql := sql || ' AND context = $3';
    ELSE
        sql := sql || ' AND context IS NULL';
    END IF;

    IF $4 IS NOT NULL THEN
        sql := sql || ' AND sender_id = $4';
    END IF;

    sql := sql || ' ORDER BY';
    IF byTimeStamp THEN
        sql := sql || ' arrive_time ASC';
    ELSE
        sql := sql || ' priority DESC';
    END IF;

    sql := sql || ' LIMIT 1'; 
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql
    USING messageFor, qid, ctxt, messageFrom;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now, the above function works fine but the resultSet does not contain column names (for example: a simple SELECT statement returns results with column names). I need to be able to
access the result of the above function in Java code as:

```
Connection con;
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select readMessage(1, 1, 1, 1, true))";
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(); 
rs.getInt(<column-name>) // for example: 'queue_id', 'context' etc.
```

instead of

```
rs.getInt(<column-index>)
```

for more readable code. How can I modify my postgresql FUNCTION to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is a really simple solution to what I want to achieve (although it doesn't modify the FUNCTION). In Java, just call

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from readMessage(1, 1, 1, 1, true))";
```

instead of

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select readMessage(1, 1, 1, 1, true))";
```